# "access into the sea" in Japanese

Tags: synonyms, english-to-japanese

How to say in Japanese "access into the sea" without using アクセス, as in

> その国は海にアクセスがある。
>   This country has an access into the sea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use 海に面する, e.g. その国は海に面している.

Comment: London has access to the sea. would this suggestion still apply in that case?

Comment: @A.Ellett No, in this case (テムズ川を通して)海に連絡している or 海につながっている would be better. 面する means something like “bordering“.